# Trouble with printer not doing anything

Tags: windows-7, networking, printing, printer, network-printer

One particular computer seems to have lots of printer problems. Right now the Lexmark CX410de isn't printing. When you print something it appears to go through fine, nothing is stuck in the queue, but nothing actually gets printed (and no messages on the LCD panel of the printer itself). I found in the printer properties "connect" was grayed out and I tried removing and readding the printer (it is networked). Something that surprised me was when Windows was searching for networked printers it found the following

```
Lexmark CX410de (sandbox-2)   http://192.168.1.191:65001/
Lexmark CX410de (sandbox-2)   http://192.168.1.191:65001/
Lexmark X546 (Lexmark international)   192.168.1.14
Lexmark CX410 series (Lexmark)   192.168.1.191
```

1. What is "sandbox"?
2. Why is the first printer shown twice
3. Why do the first two entries have http:// and the others don't?

The computer is running Windows 7 on a VM.

Answer (score 2):

Check **and remove** any printer config in the VM-software (Virtualbox / VMWare).
A network printer should not need to be there - assuming you have the virtual machine Network-enabled.

Comment: So you're saying only add printers to the guest OS (which in this case is Mac OS X)?

Comment: For printing from the guest OS, yes. As it is a network printer, the VM software only needs to pass it through the same way it lets through ANY network traffic.

Comment: it worked for the network printers but there is one label printer that is connected to the computer through a USB cable. VMware seems to screw up every so often and disconnect the printer, considering it a USB device. However even when the printer is disconnected (in the sense of new USB connection to the guest OS) the printer driver still appears in Windows. Do you know how this can be fixed?

Comment: I have not tried VMWare myself so cannot comment on it. Virtualbox on the other hand works nicely with a `Brother P9200DX` (label printer), `Datacolor Spyder 4` (screen color calibrator) and my `Epson` printer - all via USB and no tweaking, just `enable all`.